# Creating Named Ranges in Excel using Vb Script

Tags: vbscript

I created a code for creating Named Ranges in Excel using Range object but didn't work as it works in VBA. Error comes in the statement where I try to create a Range object, not sure how this could be done.

If anyone could suggest me an idea it would great.

```
Set Exobj = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
Set Newbook = Exobj.Workbooks.Add()
Newbook.SaveAs("C:\Users\ACER\Desktop\Project Folder\Test17.xlsx")

Exobj.Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\ACER\Desktop\Project Folder\Test17.xlsx")
Exobj.Visible = True

Set Myrange = Exobj.Worksheets(sheets1).Range("A1:H11") ' statement where Error comes

For each C in Myrange
If c.Value = "" Then 
C.Value ="Blank"
End if
Next

Exobj.Workbooks.Save()
Exobj.Activeworkbooks.Close()
```

Comment: I think you need to surround `sheets1` with quotes, i.e. `Set Myrange = Exobj.Worksheets("sheets1").Range("A1:H11")`

Comment: Than you, its working.

Comment: I'll post my comment as answer, cheers ;)

Comment: :) similar problem i faced when i used `Next C` it did not work, but when i made it `Next` only it worked

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to surround `sheets1` with quotes, i.e.

```
Set Myrange = Exobj.Worksheets("sheets1").Range("A1:H11")
```